# htaccess redirect url with var from no file extension to file extension

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

the problem is that for some reason googlebot gets a bunch of error 404s when crawling a certain page but everything works fine on my end, I think...

using htaccess, I have rewritten a page with vars for seo purposes, so:

```
RewriteRule   ^feeds/([^/]*)\.xml/?$   /rss/feeds.php?cat=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

so I get `www.url.com/feeds/category.xml`
instead of

```
www.url.com/feeds.php?cat=category
```

I've also ajusted all urls on the page to follow this rule and like I said everything works fine on my end... googlebot for some reason only sees `www.url.com/feeds/category` and does see the .xml extention.

not sure if it would work but I was hoping to put a rule in htaccess to redirect `www.url.com/feeds/category` to `www.url.com/feeds/category.xml` in the even that this happened, but was unsure of how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try

```
RewriteRule   ^feeds/([^/]+)/?$   /feeds/$1.xml [R,NC]
```

Which would redirect `www.url.com/feeds/category` to `www.url.com/feeds/category.xml`, using a HTTP 302 Redirect.  Remove the `R` flag if you don't want it do use the HTTP 302 Redirect, but that would make `www.url.com/feeds/category` a valid URL as far as google is concerned.  Just in case: [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).

Comment: worked perfect!!! you have NO idea how long I've been messing with this trying to figure it out... much thanks to you!